# Spring Autowire Annotation with Several Interface Implementations

Tags: java, spring

Suppose you have one interface

```
public interface A {
  public void doSomething();
}
```

and two implementation classes

```
@Component(value="aImpl1")
public class AImpl1 implements A {

}

@Component(value="aImpl2")
public class AImpl2 implements A{

}
```

And finally a class that will use an "A" implementation:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
  @Autowire
  A a;
}
```

Now if I want to inject **AImpl1** I add the **@Qualifier("aImpl1")** while if I want to inject **AImpl2** I add **@Qualifier("aImpl2")**

**The question is:** Is it possible to instruct spring somehow to look up all implementations of "A" in this case **AImpl1** and **AImpl2** and use some application specific conventions to choose the most appropriate implementation? for example in this case my convention could be use the implementation with the greatest suffix (i.e. AImpl2)?

**EDIT:** the class MyClass should not be aware at all about the implementation lookup logic, it should just find its property "a" set with an object of AImpl2.

Comment: Where do you want to keep the lookup logic? If in the XML context config file, are aliases an option? What about custom qualifiers?

Comment: What makes you think that the answer is not up to date? Are there problems with the recent Spring version? Or it does not work with specific Application Context class?

Comment: @AdrianBer the logic should be some kind of configuration for Spring and applied to all lookups. gargc gave an answer of what I exactly needed.

Comment: +1 for clear, concise code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already have hundreds of interfaces and implementations (as you said in a comment), and you do not want to refactor all the code... then is a tricky problem... and this is a tricky solution:

You could create a custom [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) and implement either the method `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` or `postProcessBeanFactory`.

This way you have access to *all* bean definitions before they are instantiated and injected. Do your logic to find which is the preferred implementation  for each one of your interfaces, and then, set that one as *primary*.

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(
            BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {

          // this method can be used to set a primary bean, although 
          // beans defined in a @Configuration class will not be avalable here.

    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {     

        // here, all beans are available including those defined by @configuration, @component, xml, etc.

        // do some magic to somehow find which is the preferred bean name for each interface 
        // you have access to all bean-definition names with: beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()
        String beanName = "aImpl2"; // let's say is this one

        // get the definition for that bean and set it as primary
        beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setPrimary(true)

    }



}
```

The hard part is to find the bean name, it depends of the specifics of your application. I guess that having a consistent naming convention will help.

**Update:**

It seems that both methods in the interface `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` can be used for this purpose. Having in mind that in the `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry`  phase, beans configured through @configuration classes are not yet available, as noted in the comments below.

On the other hand they are indeed available in `postProcessBeanFactory`.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of something along these lines. Just thought I'd add that this approach will not work for pure `@Configuration` based projects - i.e. projects that don't make use of xml configuration.

Comment: @Jonathan , your are right... BeanDefinitionRegistry doesn't contain beans defined in a @Configuration class (although it does contain @Component, @Service, etc annotated beans). But they are available in the other method: `postProcessBeanFactory`, throught the `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`. I've just did a quick test and it works. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: See **[here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7868)** on why beans defined in `@Configuration`s are not available in `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry`

Answer (score 11):

You can inject all implentations as `List`:

```
@Autowired
List<A> as;
```

or as `Map` with bean name as key:

```
@Autowired
Map<String, A> as;
```

and then choose proper implementation manually (perhaps, in a setter method):

```
@Autowired
public void setAs(Map<String, A> as) {
    this.a = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to modify the structure class MyClass. It must have one and only one property (A a);

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Configuration class you could use a method in that to make the decision of which implementation of A to return.  Then the autowired will inject the appropriate instance for that class.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    A getA() {
        // instantiate the implementation of A that you would like to have injected
        // or you could use reflection to find the correct class from the classpath.
        // return the instance
    }
}
```

This assumes you always want to use the same instance everywhere you are injecting A.  If not, then you could have different @Bean annotated methods with names to get different versions.

Comment: Yes the assumption is to always use the same implementation everywhere. The problem is that I may have hundreds of interfaces like "A" and I don't want to create a method for each interface. So what I really need is a way to customize the behavior of the @Autowire annotation and instruct it to do this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Spring Profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).